# Get friendlist for selected location

Tags: facebook, api

HI,

I am using face api to fetch friend list.Please see this code below:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '170864786279481',
  'secret' => 'cd4b835feb73c358eeb4c4df5c293a42',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
));

$session = $facebook->getSession(); 

$friendsLists = $facebook->api('/me/friends/');
```

This code gives me all friends of user But I need friends for selected location only.For example I want to get only those friends who are living in city "New york" only.Is it possible in this facebook api.Please guide me.

Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [FQL](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)'s [friend](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/friend/) and [user](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) tables.

***FQL Usage example:***

```
  $query = "SELECT ...";  

  $params = array(  
    'access_token' => $session['access_token'],  
    'query' => $query  
  ); 

  $url = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?" . http_build_query($params);  
  $data = simplexml_load_file($url);  

 // do something with the response, you should catch errors too.
```

Comment: I am not using database here so what can be query..Can you paste query examples

Comment: You can find several examples of queries in here   http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/, but here goes one:

$query = "SELECT location FROM user WHERE uid = {$session['uid']};"; // this will fetch the location for the logged in user